# How to create a custom field in Jira like "description" where as the user starts typing @, a list of suggested users will appear in a dropdown list

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

As the user starts typing @, a list of suggested users will appear in a dropdown list below the field. The user should select based on the referenced users by completely typing the JIRA user's username or choose from the list of suggested users in the dropdown list.

I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 0):

In Jira SERVER, user mentions worked only in the Comments and Description fields, no other field type supported them. Refer to [JRASERVER-3263](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-32563) for the old feature request for Jira Server.

In Jira CLOUD, user mentions work in Wiki Rendered type custom field, but the user being mentioned doesn't receive a notification that they were mentioned. Refer to [JRACLOUD-32563](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-32563) for that feature request.